# Insert checkbox value into database SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert the value of a checkbox into the database.

But in the database the column is null.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAWAF;Initial Catalog=waterreport;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
      string chkek = "finish";
    }
    SqlCommand tump;
    SqlCommand orugg;
    string tmp = " UPDATE reportonetmp set finish_repair_date='" + textBox1.Text + "', finish_repair_hour='" + textBox2.Text + "', ca_of_problem='" + comboBox1.Text + "', line_type='" + comboBox2.Text + "', situation='" + textBox3.Text + "', diameter_of_pipes ='" + comboBox3.Text + "', timenoww3 ='" + label7.Text + "' WHERE no like '" + label13.Text + "'";
    tump = new SqlCommand(tmp, con);
    tump.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string org = " UPDATE reportone set finish_repair_date='" + textBox1.Text + "', finish_repair_hour='" + textBox2.Text + "', ca_of_problem='" + comboBox1.Text + "', line_type='" + comboBox2.Text + "', situation='" + textBox3.Text + "', diameter_of_pipes ='" + comboBox3.Text + "', timenoww3 ='" + label7.Text + "',checkk ='" + chkek + "' WHERE no like '" + label13.Text + "'";
    orugg = new SqlCommand(org, con);
    orugg.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using .NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: because you only set finish" if its checked. it will be missing if its not

Comment: P.S. Wouldn't you be better storing checkk as a true/false field (e.g. bit in SQL-server)? If you store this string, then you have to parse it again when you retrieve the data, in order to know what to display.

Comment: Looks like you have `chkek` variable defined somewhere else too and you are creating another `chkek` in the `if` block. This way you are not changing the value of the proper variable. you should have `if` block as `if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
      chkek = "finish";
    }` And then try.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other problems (like having non-parametrised queries), are you sure that your DB column is called 'checkk'?

If that's correct, I would convert that DB column into a bit one (if you're using SQL Server) or boolean and updating it like this, instead of using an string variable:

```
"',checkk ='" + checkBox1.Checked
```

Answer (score -1):

put oncheckchanged on checkbox control in aspx page and if checked means set values to 1 else 0(put if condition   in checkedchanged event, so simple).same way you can get from database if value 1 means checkbox ID.Checked like this enough